# Can't run glxgears using XQuartx

Tags: linux, macos, opengl, xquartz

I am trying to run glxgears on a remote Linux server using XQuarts 2.7.11 on macOS Mojave (10.14.6), but I get the following error:

```
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Is this issue due to the fact that the OpenGL version on my MacBook is 2.1, or is it an issue with OpenGL on the Linux seerver?

I need OpenGL 3 or 4 in order to run Unreal Engine on the Linux server.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a number of causes. First off, if you are using Ubuntu 16.04 as the remote server, [try to delete off the mesa version of libGL.so](https://askubuntu.com/a/903488/75760)

```
$ sudo rm /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
```

Basically just look for different versions of `libL.so` and remove those unneeded or outdated

```
$ sudo ldconfig -p | grep -i gl.so
```

If you are using Steam on Linux, [there is a specific issue](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/5884#issuecomment-437690163) where you need to use `libnvidia-compute-418` and `libnvidia-gl-418`

Note that on some systems, the Mesa version of LibGL might be named something like `d /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_mesa.so.0.0.0`